# Can a function have both a global maximum, and minimum?

Tags: functions

Can a function have a global maximum, and minimum?

Comment: Certainly! $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$. Of course, you should want to have imagined this a priori, which you could have.

Comment: A constant function has a lot of global maxima and minima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function on a closed bounded interval $[a,b]$, then $f(x)$ will have a global maximum and a global minimum on $[a,b]$! (This is a theorem.)

Comment: Extreme Value Theorem?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 1):

If you learn continuous functions over a closed interval, they will have global mean and global max on that inverval. For example $f(x) = x^3 - x^2, 0 \le x \le 1$. You can use $1$st or $2$nd derivative test to find these extreme values for $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$  and $f(0)=1$ does.

Note here the domain is unbounded, but the function achieves its min and max (it just dies out on the tails).

You don't have rely on the "cheat" of a compact domain to realize a global min and max.